# Woocommerce - Add a featured video for product

Tags: php, wordpress, video, woocommerce

I am working on a wordpress plugin based on woocommerce and as a part of it I would ask site users to post products from front end form. I am saving the submitted data as `post_type=product` so that I can enable users to create their own products based on woocommerce in which I have succeeded.

Now I want to allow users to upload a video for their product from the same front end form and I need to attach the video to the product. Finally the video should be displayed in the place of featured image in `single-product` page.

What I noticed is woocommerce is allowing only image filetypes by default but I also want to add filetypes like mp4 and display it instead of product image. Can anyone help understanding the way to do it?

Comment: [YITH WooCommerce Featured Video](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-featured-video/)

Comment: @Karthik This plugin will allow only youtube and vimeo videos where as I am looking for custom video upload which need to happen programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing it using a custom filed will be easy for you because you are using a front end form for this. You can use `update_post_meta` function easily.

You can use ACF or any other plugin to make custom fields easily.

Comment: Thanks @Dhanuka. I agree with the custom field aspect but is there any way to replace the product image with this video?

Comment: @krishna89  give this plugin a try  https://wordpress.org/plugins/replace-featured-image-with-video/

Comment: ok. But still I think that custom field aspect is the best way to go

Comment: I am having similar issue please help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62778904/how-to-stop-embed-video-in-model-popup-in-javascript-woocommerce?answertab=active#tab-top